# Trying to read formatted file in C

Tags: c, readfile

i'm trying to read a formatted file in C this is a sample line of the file:

> SURNAME;NAME;MINUTES'SECONDS''ONE-HUNDREDTHS OF A SECOND

I wrote this code:

```
 while(!feof(fp))
 {
    fscanf(fp,"%[^;]s",surname);
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
    fscanf(fp,"%[^;]s",name);
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&c);
    fscanf(fp,"%d'%d''%d",&min,&sec,&sec_cent);
    fscanf(fp,"\n");
}
```

It works well with the name and surname strings, but it doesn't extract the time MINUTES'SECONDS''ONE-HUNDREDTHS OF A SECOND and i don't know why

Can someone help me?

Comment: and I don;t know why you did not check the return value of `fscanf()`?

Comment: I debugged the code and the `fscanf()`  returns  **6356238**

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Read the documentation of functions you use and **always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error relevant for program execution.

Comment: @user3121023 it doesn't work

Comment: @Marian yes error in recopying the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things you may want to change in your code:

- Always check the return value of `scanf` (or `fscanf`) to see if all the data were read.
- [Don't use `feof()` to control a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).
- You don't need to extract the `'\n'` with scanf, unless you are going to use `getline()` afterwards.
- You don't need the `s` too, with that format specifier, but you should prevent buffer overflows limiting the number of chars read for each field.
- You can use the modifier `%*c` to skip a char (the `;`).

This should be fine:

```
int min = 0, sec = 0, sec_cent = 0;
char name[128], surname[128];

while ( fscanf(fp, "%127[^;]%*c%127[^;]%*c%2d'%2d''%2d", surname, name,
                                                         &min, &sec, &sec_cent) == 5 ) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much